# nsis script flaged as trojan by avira

Tags: nsis, virus, false-positive

My nsis script is flagged as a trojan "tr/kdv.hg.1" when I reconfigure my nsis script to do some parts of the script there is no problem.
But the script all together gives the false positive. Does anybody now which functions of nsis are likely causing this?

Answer (score 0):

NSISdl, INetC and Dialer are the most common triggers AFAIK. Submit a sample [here](http://analysis.avira.com/samples/index.php) to get it fixed...

There is an old thread about Avira on the [forum](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=290285).

Comment: my program does not use any of these plugins for downloading files from the web. Are there any other?